# reading properties from ini file in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting, and I have a need which I am explaining by using a sample example. I have a property file which will contain data as shown below :

```
object1 : propertyA

object2 : property1 property2

object3 : propertyxyz
```

Note : On the whole I have some objects which can have any number of properties. And I need to keep this in a property files so that it can be changed as per need.

All I need is if I get object 3 as a user input then my code should print all the respective properties.

I have tried using .ini files, but I dont want to use any external parsers. And which ever comes with bash seems to not helping me in this case. if I use grep then I would have to split the properties using some regex.

.ini file which I created :

```
[object1]

property=propertyA


[object2]

property=property1

property=property2

[object3]

property=propertyxya
```

I am looking for a solution in which if I select an object ( which in case of ini files it is a section) then I should get all the properties in an array.

So is there any thing which is predefined in bash or do I need to write using grep n regex only.

Comment: What about `awk`, it is best suited for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done *pretty* easily using `Awk`, just do the below to store the contents in a `bash` array.

```
read -p "Enter object to get properties for: " objectname
all_properties=($(awk -F '=' -v input="${objectname}" '$1 ~ input{flag=1; next} $1 ~ /\[object/{flag=0; next} flag && NF {split($0,arr,"="); print arr[2] }  config.ini))
```

Now loop the array to print the properties,

```
for property in "${all_properties[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\n" "$property"
done
```

(or) just

```
printf "%s\n" "${all_properties[@]}"
```

The `Awk` command works as follows:-

1. Getting the user input in a variable and passing to `Awk` using the `-v` syntax and doing a regex match `$1 ~ input` to match the line containing user input, say `object1`
2. I am enabling a flag to start marking lines from this line on-wards and resetting the flag once the next object starts, see `$1 ~ /\[object/{flag=0; next}`
3. The condition `flag && NF` takes care of processing only non-empty lines and only property values after the requested object.
4. Now on the selected lines, using the `split()` function in `Awk`, we can extract the value of property and print it, which will be later stored in the array.

Put the line with `read` and the line below as shown in a `bash` script with she-bang set to `#!/bin/bash` and run it.

E.g. in a complete script as

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
read -p "Enter object to get properties for: " objectname
all_properties=($(awk -F '=' -v input="${objectname}" '$1 ~ input{flag=1; next} $1 ~ /\[object/{flag=0; next} flag && NF {split($0,arr,"="); print arr[2] }' config.ini ))

printf "%s\n" "${all_properties[@]}"
```

A few sample runs on the script.

```
$ bash script.sh
Enter object to get properties for: object1
propertyA

$ bash script.sh
Enter object to get properties for: object2
property1
property2

$ bash script.sh
Enter object to get properties for: object3
propertyxya
```

Comment: where are you passing section id here. I can see you are reading the parameter but you are matching with "property" , can you explain some more.. I will be passing object id as input and then read all properties.

Comment: @Haj: Can you see the updated answer and let know if it worked?

Comment: it does not seem to be working for me. My suspect is that you are using "object" as a keyword to reach to the next section. But for my case objects have random names with no such common characters which we can use. its just that I am going to write object names in [ ]

Comment: @Haj: In that case for the flag reset part, `$1 ~ /\[object/{flag=0; next}` remove the `object` from it and just have  ` `$1 ~ /\[/{flag=0; next}` to mark the start of next pattern

Answer (score 3):

For your `filename.ini` file:

```
[object1]
property=propertyA

[object2]
property=property1
property=property2

[object3]
property=propertyxya
```

You can use `awk` to can capture the [object] line. Then for every subsequent `key=value` line you can merge it with the parent [object] line:

```
awk '/^\[.*\]$/{obj=$0}/=/{print obj $0}' filename.ini
```

Which produces this intermediate output:

```
[object1]property=propertyA
[object2]property=property1
[object2]property=property2
[object3]property=propertyxya
```

Then we use `grep '[object2]property='` to filter the output to get the lines we want:

```
[object2]property=property1
[object2]property=property2
```

Then we use either `sed 's/.*=//'` or `perl -pe 's/.*=//'` to retrieve just the values:

```
property1
property2
```

Generalizing we have:

```
read_ini_file() {
    local obj=$1
    local key=$2
    local file=$3
    awk '/^\[.*\]$/{obj=$0}/=/{print obj $0}' $file \
        | grep '^\['$obj'\]'$key'=' \
        | perl -pe 's/.*=//'
}

# read "filename.ini" for "[object2] property" lines
# i.e. property1 property2.

result=$(read_ini_file object2 property filename.ini)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, where `XXXXXXX` is the object name :

```
awk '/\[XXXXXXX\]/{flag=1;next}/\[.*\]/{flag=0}flag && NF' test.ini
```

For example :

```
awk '/\[object1\]/{flag=1;next}/\[.*\]/{flag=0}flag && NF' test.ini
property=propertyA

awk '/\[object2\]/{flag=1;next}/\[.*\]/{flag=0}flag && NF' test.ini
property=property1
property=property2

awk '/\[object3\]/{flag=1;next}/\[.*\]/{flag=0}flag && NF' test.ini
property=propertyxya
```

See this post for more info : [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38972737/1983854).

For the formatting in an array, it will depend what the array should look like

Comment: @Haj If the only purpose is to display the value without keeping the key, you can one line your script like : `awk -F"=" '/\['"$1"'\]/{flag=1;next}/\[.*\]/{flag=0}flag && NF { print $2 }' config.ini` and invoke it as follow : `script.sh objectName`

Answer (score 0):

There is a project which provides a function to parse ini files: [bash_ini_parser](https://github.com/rudimeier/bash_ini_parser)

It requires bash only, no other tools needed.

Answer (score 0):

Though this reply is late by 4 years, just putting it here for anyone looking for a cleaner utility.
Check out the [simple ini parser](https://github.com/rudimeier/bash_ini_parser) by Ruediger Meier.

```
curl -SSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rudimeier/bash_ini_parser/master/read_ini.sh > $HOME/bin/read_ini.sh
```

Use above curl to get the script.

```
USAGE
-----

You must source the bash file into your script:

> . read_ini.sh

and then use the read_ini function, defined as:

> read_ini INI_FILE [SECTION] [[--prefix|-p] PREFIX] [[--booleans|b] [0|1]]

If SECTION is supplied, then only the specified section of the file will
be processed.

After running the read_ini function, variables corresponding to the ini
file entries will be available to you. Naming convention for variable
names is:

PREFIX__SECTION__VARNAME

PREFIX is 'INI' by default (but can be changed with the --prefix option),
SECTION and VARNAME are the section name and variable name respectively.

Additionally you can get a list of all these variable names:
PREFIX__ALL_VARS
and get a list of sections:
PREFIX__ALL_SECTIONS
and the number of sections:
PREFIX__NUMSECTIONS
```